# How prove this $[\sqrt{23n}]\{\sqrt{23n}\}>3$

Tags: number-theory

show that

for any positive integer $n\ne 23m^2,m\in N$, have
$$[\sqrt{23n}]\{\sqrt{23n}\}>3$$
and $\{x\}=x-[x]$

I have post this [How prove this $|\{n\sqrt{3}\}-\{n\sqrt{2}\}|>\frac{1}{20n^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465470/how-prove-this-n-sqrt3-n-sqrt2-frac120n3)

and This problem have nice methods?

my idea:
let
$[\sqrt{23n}]=m\in N^{+},\{\sqrt{23n}\}=r\in[0,1)$,then
$$\Longleftrightarrow mr>3\Longleftrightarrow m>\dfrac{3}{r}$$

Comment: oh,$n\neq 23a^2,a\in N$,Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Note that the equation $x^2-230y^2=-5$ has solution $x=15$, $y=1$.

Using the fundamental solution of the Pell equation $x^2-230y^2=1$, we conclude that the equation $x^2-230y^2=-5$ has infinitely many integer solutions.

If $(x,y)$ is such a solution, let $n=10y^2$. Then $23n$ is $5$ more than a perfect square.

Note that the fractional part $\{\sqrt{23n}\}$ is $\sqrt{23n}-x$. Thus from the factorization $x^2-23n=(x-\sqrt{23n})(x+\sqrt{23n})$ we obtain
$$\{\sqrt{23n}\}=\frac{5}{x+\sqrt{23n}}.$$

For large $n$, we have $x\approx \sqrt{23n}$. It follows that 
$$\lfloor\sqrt{23n}\rfloor\{\sqrt{23n}\}\approx 2.5.$$
As $n=10y^2\to\infty$, the error in the approximation goes to $0$. So we can assert, for example, that there are infinitely many $n$, such that $23n$ is not a perfect square, and $\lfloor\sqrt{23n}\rfloor\{\sqrt{23n}\}\lt 2.6$.

Answer (score 5):

$\{ \sqrt{23 \cdot n} \} = 0$ infinitely often so it is not true.

It also [fails](http://pastebin.com/bgTw8us5) for $n=3$ and many others:

```
3
10
23
42
63
92
127
162
207
258
307
368
435
498
575
658
735
828
927
1018
1127
1242
1347
1472
1603
1722
1863
2010
2143
2300
2463
2610
2783
2962
3123
3312
3507
3682
3887
4098
4287
4508
4735
4938
5175
5418
5635
5888
6147
6378
6647
6922
7167
7452
7743
8002
8303
8610
8883
9200
9523
9810
```

Comment: Yes, I have edit,Thank you

Comment: oh,Thank you,.it seem  this problem  is not true,

Comment: No, This problem is true,,